# PHP , Search and Replace array element inside string

Tags: php, arrays, string, if-statement, replace

i try to search and replace array element inside string but don't know how to do this !
my code ex :

```
$string_text = 'some random text with random lenght ';

function check_strings($string_text){

$new_string_text = $string_text; //random text with randon lenght 
$array_of_3000 = ['some','text','hello','no','why','oh','random']; // array with lenght of 3000
$text_tokens = explode($new_string_text,' '); // to make it array 
foreach($text_tokens as $token_index =>$token ){  // loop on $text_tokens 
    if (in_array($token, $array_of_3000)){   // if token in $array_of_3000 -> change token with link 

        $token_link = sprintf("<a href='<?php echo site_url('/%s'); ?>' >  %s </a>",$tokens,$tokens); // changeing $token to  html link 
        // update $new_string_text , $token with -> $token_link 
        $new_string_text = str_replace($tokens,$token_link,$tokens);


    }
}
    return $new_string_text;
}
 //  text =  'some random text with random lenght ' -> same , text , random x2 are in $array_of_3000 so need to change them with html link 
    // random x2 -> if find more as 1 just link 1 of them 
    // " <a href='<?php echo site_url('/some'); ?>' >  some </a>"
    // " <a href='<?php echo site_url('/text '); ?>' >  text </a>"
    // " <a href='<?php echo site_url('/random '); ?>' >  random </a>" 
// output -> all words in input string if can finded in $array_of_3000 need change with it link
```

if statement (in_array()) not work and i dont know how to find match words
how can i do it ?
thanks for your helps :)

thanks every one i fix it
the code is work fine now ```

```
        if (in_array($token, $array_of_words)){   // if token in $array_of_3000 -> change token with link 
    
            $token_link = sprintf("<a   href='<?php echo site_url('/%s'); ?>' >  %s </a>",$tokens,$tokens); // changeing $token to  html link 
            // update $new_string_text , $token with -> $token_link 
            $new_string_text = str_replace($tokens,$token_link,$tokens);
    
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: please improve the clarity of your question. Also, you could add an input -> output example of what you want to achieve. I'm not clear of what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Gass thanks i try to make it more clear , i have some random text and array of 3000 words .if any of array elements are in text change them with link

Comment: Is there anything not working with the given code? If yes, please share more details about the problem you are facing

Comment: @NicoHaase  yes if statement not work . first i need to check if the string have any of the array change it to html link

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. What **exactly** is not working? What have you tried to make it work?

Comment: i updated my answer to include a solution for your code if you still having problems / errors

Answer (score 1):

You can use the php [str_replace (php manual)](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.str-replace.php) function

str_replace accept arrays in arguments

example:

```
$str= 'random text idk';
$tokens = ['random', 'idk'];
$newTokens = ['token1', 'token2'];

$str = str_replace($tokens, $newTokens, $str));
// value of str: "token1 text token2"
```

for your example you can use this

```
function check_strings($string_text){
    $array_of_3000 = ['some', 'text', 'hello', 'no', 'why', 'oh', 'random'];
    $array_of_3000_replacements = [];
        
    foreach ($array_of_3000 as $oldToken) {
        $array_of_3000_replacements[] = sprintf("<a href='<?php echo site_url('/%s'); ?>' >  %s </a>", $oldToken, $oldToken);
    }

    return str_replace($array_of_3000, $array_of_3000_replacements, $string_text);
}
```

Comment: hey thanks for your answer , i try this but i don't know why it not work find in loops

Comment: why you need loops ? just give str_replace arrays of oldTokens and newTokens and the function inside will loop through the tokens to replace all

Comment: i need to check every words in the text with array elements  if word is in array need too change the word with link so i think i need do it inside loop on text and make new link for ea word

Comment: what you are tying to do is exactly what the function is doing, put your words in an array, put the links on other array, then $yourFinalText = str_replace($words, $links, $string)
if any word in the array words exist in the string, it will be replaced by the equivalent link in the links array (read carefully the example i putted on my answer)